# Opengraph link previews in Jekyll

Tags: markdown, jekyll, facebook-opengraph, static-site

When you insert links in modern writing websites, they usually display preview of the page instead of the link (if there is no surrounding text in the paragraph).

I would like the same experience when i add some links to posts on my jekyll website, a way to render their previews.

This is very convenient for readers. Sometimes previews mistakenly called "embeds".

Is there a way, inside Jekyll page/post, to generate a "preview card" with text/image preview according to the [Open Graph protocol](https://ogp.me/)?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## Showing rich text previews of your Jekyll site elsewhere

> Is there a way to generate a "preview card" with text/image preview according to the Open Graph protocol instead of just a plain link in a markdown site of the static site generator Jekyll?

Yes, this is possible. The [jekyll-seo-tag plugin](https://jekyll.github.io/jekyll-seo-tag/) already sets propertys of the metadata of the Open Graph Protocoll for you, as you can see in [its template](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll-seo-tag/blob/master/lib/template.html).

Jekyll's default theme,

> [Minima](https://jekyll.github.io/minima/)  already comes with the `jekyll-seo-tag` plugin preinstalled to make sure your site gets the most usefull meta tags. <sup>[[1]](https://github.com/jekyll/minima#plugins)</sup>

The plugin reads the values from your `_config.yaml` to set the properties. Some values are

- `title` for `og:title` and `og:site_name`
- `description` for `og:description`
- `url` for `og:url`

It is also possible to specify `og:image` with the `jekyll-seo-tag` plugin as described in the [advanced usage section](https://jekyll.github.io/jekyll-seo-tag/advanced-usage/#customizing-image-output) of its docs. Add the following to the front matter of your post:

```yaml
image:
  path: /your/fancy/image.png
  height: 100
  width: 100
```

It is also possible to specify a default image, see [front matter defaults in the Jekyll docs](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/configuration/front-matter-defaults/)

I tried this all with [my own blog](https://blog.kalehmann.de/) - also generated with Jekyll.

I have added an `og:image` for [this post](https://blog.kalehmann.de/blog/2018/11/11/sleepdungeon.html). You can check its source on [GitHub](https://github.com/kalehmann/blog-kalehmann-de/blob/master/_posts/2018-11-11-sleepdungeon.markdown).

Before adding the image, the preview in Telegram desktop looked like this:

[image: Telegram desktop link preview without image]

After adding the `og:image`, it looked like this:

[image: Telegram desktop link preview with image]

### What to do if my image does not show up?

There are several reasons for this.

- Maybe your image is too large? Several sites suggest to keep the preview image below 300 KB
- Your link preview is already cached. Telegram offers a nice solution for this - the [`@webpagebot`](https://telegram.me/webpagebot). You can send your links to this bot and it will update the cache.

## Showing previews of other links on your Jekyll site

There are two ways to generate a preview for links on your Jekyll site:

1. Generate the link preview on the server
2. Let the client generate the preview with JavaScript

### Server side preview generation

- **Advantages:**

  - your clients do not need JavaScript
- **Disadvantages:**

  - the preview is generated with your site and only updated when your site is updated
  - Custom plugins do not work with GitHub pages

There exists a Jekyll plugin for that - [`jekyll-preview-tag`](https://github.com/aleks/jekyll_preview_tag):

- first install the required gems `nokogiri`, `open-uri`, `ruby-readability` and `digest`, e.g.

  ```
   bundle add nokogiri
   bundle add open-uri
   bundle add ruby-readability
   bundle add digest
  ```
- Now download the file `preview_tag.rb` and place it in the `_plugins` folder of your site.
- Create the `_cache` directory
- Add your link into your markdown, e.g:

  ```
  {% preview https://mycoolsite.com %}
  ```

Per default this renders only text:

[image: text only preview generated with jekyll-preview-tag]

However, you can add a method that extracts the `og:image` tag:

```rb
def get_og_image_url(source)
    if source.css('meta[property="og:image"]').first
        return source.css('meta[property="og:image"]').first["content"]
    end
    return ""
end
```

I created a fork that demonstrates this on [my GitHub profile](https://github.com/kalehmann/jekyll_preview_tag), you can easily modificate it.

The preview looks like this:

[image: image preview generated with jekyll-preview-tag]

### Client side preview generation

There are several JavaScript libraries available, that generate the preview for you.

- **Advantages**

  - the preview is always up to date
- **Disadvantages**

  - the client needs JavaScript
  - most of the tools rely on external and often unfree services due the [Same-Origin-Policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy)

You may want to look at

- [JQuery preview](https://embedly.github.io/jquery-preview/demo/)

Comment: Thanks. this is really useful information. However, the question is related to showing previews when inserting external limk to jekyll post

Comment: @Croll Hmm, I misunterstood your question then. Nevertheless I got some ideas and will update my answer

Comment: @Croll, I wrote a big update. I hope this helps you

Comment: Nice work! I will add a way to bypass github limitation for server-side approach, if any

Comment: You can still build the site locally and push the result to the `gh-pages` branch. But GitHub itself will not rebuild the site for you

Comment: Thank you, I had been trying to track down how to add `og:image` to posts for months. The sample front matter in your blog post resolved it for me.

Comment: @kalehmann your solution looks awesome but I think preview_tag.rb doesn't work with dependencies recent versions. I don't know ruby to really diagnose the problem.