# Open Graph for Jekyll not showing as expected

Tags: jekyll, facebook-opengraph, github-pages, share-open-graph

Knowing little about programming, I followed the descriptions on [Opengraph link previews in Jekyll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57493239/opengraph-link-previews-in-jekyll) and https://jekyll.github.io/jekyll-seo-tag/installation/ , trying to set up Open Graph preview for my website.

I can see `property="og:title"` etc tags on the website pages' HTML code as a result.

However, when sharing a link on Telegram, there's no preview for most of the pages except for the home page https://www.lintj.com/

To check my code:
https://github.com/gclintj/test

Answer (score 0):

Per kalehmann,

> First of all, you don't have the minima gem in your dependencies, try
> `bundle add minima`
>
> Then you have `<link rel="canonical" href="http://localhost:4000/">`
> in
> https://github.com/gclintj/test/blob/gh-pages/_layouts/default.html#L24.
> This prevents your preview from being displayed. You can safely remove
> this line, as the jekyll-seo-tag plugin will add it again.

Following kalehmann's instructions above, the problem has been solved.